# Checking for some exact lines in each file in directory and subdirectories

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to do the following and running into errors,what is going wrong?

1.Open each file in the directory and subdirectories based on the argument

2.Check if each file has the copyright info exactly the 3 lines

```
 Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc. 
 All Rights Reserved.
 Company Confidential and Proprietary.
```

The code:

```
import os
import sys
userstring="Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary."
print len(sys.argv)
print sys.argv[1]
if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    sys.exit('Usage: python.py <build directory>')
for r,d,f in os.walk(sys.argv[1]):
    for files in f:
        with open(os.path.join(r, files), "r") as file:
            if ''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip() != userstring:
                print files
```

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: I corrected the indentation and comments, presuming that it was an issue posting here. `//` is not a Python comment, `#` is.

Comment: I reworked on it and updated the code but i am not getting the desired result..no files are getting printed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe by changing these lines:

```
file = open(files, "r")
if userstring not in line:  #check if each file contains the lines
    print file
```

To these:

```
with open(os.path.join(r, files), "r") as file:
    if ''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip() != userstring:
        print files
```

You achieve your goal. But when you're working with files, you should be aware about bad files bad formatting and exception handling and etc.

Comment: I edited the question with the latest code..there are no errors but I am not getting the desired output..no files are getting printed..any inputs on where I am going wrong/?

Comment: Your new `userstring` defintion is not match with your expectation, test with this `"Copyright (c) 2012 Company, Inc.\nAll Rights Reserved.\nCompany Confidential and Proprietary."`

Comment: I tried with that aswell,just doesnt print any files..i doubt the script is reading any files content or not

Comment: So use some debug prints, add `print ''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip()` line after `open` statement to check the files contents.

Comment: adding print ''.join(file.readlines()[:3]).strip() doesnt print naything..what is this join doing anyway?

Comment: @user1927233 Oops, check out my answer, I had updated the `open` statement, you should join the file name with the file path.

Comment: is it just reading the first three lines in a file?if its the case its not right..it has to ready the entire file and check if these 3 lines are present

Comment: one more major problem was quotes around "sys.argv[1]",I removed them..but please answer my question,what is join doing and [:3] doing?

Comment: @user1927233 Look at these: http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.join and http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#lists

Comment: I thought the same..basically you are checking the 3rdline in every file which is no way related to what I want..completely baseless suggestion